# Having problems with imports in dart 2.17 in vscode

Tags: dart

I'm having problems with VS Code not able to find packages after updating to dart 2.17. This worked fine while using dart 2.16.

With the following dart file:

```dart
  import 'package:test/test.dart';
  ...
```

And the following `pubspec.yaml`

```
dev_dependencies:
  test: ^1.17.4
```

VSCode is showing that there's a problem:

> Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:test/test.dart'.
> Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.

The project can be run from CLI fine, just that VS Code IDE is showing issues to resolve.

This is using:

- VSCode Version: 1.67.2
- Dart extension in VSCode: v3.40.0
- macOS 12.4
- Dart SDK version: 2.17.1 (stable) (Tue May 17 17:58:21 2022 +0000) on "macos_arm64"

Note: This is a pure dart project, no flutter libraries are installed/used.